# Android build failed and error message is "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/apache/pdfbox/debugger/real.png'"

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

In my Android App I used pdfbox to generate PDF file. I was able to compile but when I build and try to deploy to a simulator. I got the following error message: "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/apache/pdfbox/debugger/real.png'". In my build.gradle file I include a libs path and all the jar were copy to libs path

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
// implementation 'libs/*.jar'
implementation files('libs/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar')

All the jars were included in the app/libs path
The following jars were included in the app/libs path
jfreechart-1.0.0.19 jar
pdfbox-2.0.13.jar
pdfbox-app-2.0.13.jar
pdfbox-debugger-2.0.13.jar
pdfbox-tools-2.0.13.jar
```

Comment: pdfbox-app and pdfbox-debugger both contain pdfbox, that might be the reason. And pdfbox-app also contains the debugger. And finally, I'm not sure it will run at all, unless you are using pdfbox for Android.

Comment: may be I can try remove both pdfbox-app and pdfbox-debugger then.

Comment: After removing pdfbox-app and pdfbox-debugger. I am getting this error instead.  More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

Comment: after I add the following line. Build works.                                 
       android { ...                                                         
       packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'}
    }

Comment: Consider answering yourself... I prefer not, I don't use gradle at all.